# get all facebook likes on android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am currently using the code below to get my facebook likes but I get only 25 and also pagination with next.But the limit is always 25.And its always current page and next page.I want all likes in one go.How can I do it in android in 1 go? or should I have asynctask running till there is no next option in response?

```
new Request(facebook.getSession(),
        "/me/likes",
        null,
        HttpMethod.GET,
        new Request.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(Response response) {


        JSONArray   arr = null;
        GraphObject go  = response.getGraphObject();
        JSONObject  jso = go.getInnerJSONObject();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `offset` property. This snippet loads the next 25 likes:

```
new Request(facebook.getSession(),
    "/me/likes?offset=25",
    null,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    new Request.Callback() {
    // ...
```

Comment: I get null when I do this

Comment: So `response` is `null` with my code but not with yours? Strange... You can try to use `"/me/likes?limit=1000"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `offset` and `limit` properties to 'page' through facebook responses as follows:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("limit","400");
params.putString("offset","800");
new Request( Session.getActiveSession(),
     "/me/likes",
     params,
     HttpRequest.GET,
     new RequestCallback() {
          // handle results here
     }
).executeAsync();
```

To 'page' through results, simply increase the offset until you receive no more results. And you obviously don't need to read 400 likes per request, so feel free to change that and the offset amount as needed.